# toggle function broken on accordion element

Tags: javascript, html, accordion

```
function openAccordion() {
            let activeAccordion = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion active')[0]
            if (activeAccordion) {
                activeAccordion.classList.remove('active')
                activeAccordion.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
            }


            let accordion = event.currentTarget
            accordion.classList.toggle('active')
            let panel = accordion.nextElementSibling;
            if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
                panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
                panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
        }
```

Code above is supposed to toggle an accordion button and display only one at a time. But it's broken/bugged.

Without the activeAccordion part, toggling works just fine, but it doesnt close an opened panel when another is opened.

With the activeAccordion part, it closes the panel when another opens but toggling stops working.

How can I restructure this ?